# phpmyadmin can't login with non-root users

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, phpmyadmin, virtualmin, webmin

I just started learning to manage Linux web hosting. After installed webmin/virtualmin on Ubunto 14.04, I used the install script of virtualmin to install phpmyadmin. The problem is, I can only use root to login phpmyadmin, in the database, I can see other accounts I created through Virtualmin(I created them through creating new virtual host servers and I have no problem logging them into webmin/virtualmin), but when I tried to login phpmyadmin with them, I got access denied. I login with root account and grant all privilages for other accounts but still can't login with them.

So what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: "I just started learning to manage Linux web hosting." Next lesson: No more phpMyAdmin, no more control panels.

Comment: Well thanks for the infomation. But my goal is not to master linux, I am simply a webdesigner who wants to have a little more control over server issues.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a common source of security vulnerabilities and compromised servers, and is unnecessary. You're much better off using a client like Sequel Pro (http://www.sequelpro.com/) or Navicat (http://www.navicat.com/). Control panels are a similar source of compromise, and they also typically make maintaining a server significantly harder in the long run. For that reason, control panels are actually entirely off-topic here on ServerFault.

Comment: Did you do a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after adding the new accounts?